# phpunit in Zend Framework 2 working, but not running any of the assertions

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit

So this is super annoying. I have one test file with one test function and some assertions in it. I can show that when I run `phpunit` in the command line that the test function runs (by writing to the log) but none of the assertions pass or fail. It seems like there's a PHP error when the assertion is supposed to run but nothing appears in the output or my `/var/log/nginx/error.log` file. **What do I need to do to get my assertions to run?**

Here's the output when I run `phpunit`:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.38 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from <PATH_TO_TEST_FOLDER>/test/phpunit.xml

hello1
```

**Notice how there's no summary like you see [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#a-failing-test-case).**

Here's the `<PATH_TO_TEST_FOLDER>/test/ApplicationTest/Controller/IndexControllerTest.php` file:

```
<?php
namespace ApplicationTest\Controller;

use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;

class IndexControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
    protected $traceError = true;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $dir = getcwd();
        $this->setApplicationConfig(
            include $dir . '/config/application.config.php'
        );
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
    {
        error_log('hello1');

        $this->assertEquals(true, false);

        error_log('hello2');
    }
}
```

Here's my `<PATH_TO_TEST_FOLDER>/test/Bootstrap.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace ApplicationTest;

use Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory;
use Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use RuntimeException;

error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
chdir( __DIR__ );

class Bootstrap {

    protected static $serviceManager;

    public static function init() {

        // Load the user-defined test configuration file, if it exists; otherwise, load
        if ( is_readable( __DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php' ) ) {
            $testConfig = include __DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php';
        } else {
            $testConfig = include __DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php.dist';
        }

        $zf2ModulePaths = array ();

        if ( isset( $testConfig['module_listener_options']['module_paths'] ) ) {
            $modulePaths = $testConfig['module_listener_options']['module_paths'];
            foreach ( $modulePaths as $modulePath ) {
                if ( ($path = static::findParentPath( $modulePath )) ) {
                    $zf2ModulePaths[] = $path;
                }
            }
        }

        static::initAutoloader();

        // use ModuleManager to load this module and it's dependencies
        $config = array (
            'module_listener_options' => array (
                    'module_paths' => $zf2ModulePaths 
            ),
            'modules' => array (
                    'Application' 
            ) 
        );

        $serviceManager = new ServiceManager( new ServiceManagerConfig() );
        $serviceManager->setService( 'ApplicationConfig', $config );
        $serviceManager->get( 'ModuleManager' )->loadModules();
        static::$serviceManager = $serviceManager;
    }

    public static function chroot() {

        $rootPath = dirname( static::findParentPath( 'module' ) );
        chdir( $rootPath );
    }

    public static function getServiceManager() {

        return static::$serviceManager;
    }

    protected static function initAutoloader() {

        $vendorPath = static::findParentPath('vendor');

        $zf2Path = getenv('ZF2_PATH');
        if (!$zf2Path) {
            if (defined('ZF2_PATH')) {
                $zf2Path = ZF2_PATH;
            } elseif (is_dir($vendorPath . '/ZF2/library')) {
                $zf2Path = $vendorPath . '/ZF2/library';
            } elseif (is_dir($vendorPath . '/zendframework/zendframework/library')) {
                $zf2Path = $vendorPath . '/zendframework/zendframework/library';
            }
        }

        if (!$zf2Path) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or'
            . ' define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.'
            );
        }

        if (file_exists($vendorPath . '/autoload.php')) {
            include $vendorPath . '/autoload.php';
        }

        include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
        AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'autoregister_zf' => true,
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        ));
    }

    protected static function findParentPath( $path ) {

        $previousDir = '.';
        while ( !is_dir( $dir . '/' . $path ) ) {
            $dir = dirname( $dir );
            if ( $previousDir === $dir ) {
                return false;
            }
            $previousDir = $dir;
        }
        return $dir . '/' . $path;
    }
}

Bootstrap::init();
Bootstrap::chroot();
```

Here's my `<PATH_TO_TEST_FOLDER>/test/phpunit.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit bootstrap="Bootstrap.php" colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="application">
            <directory>./ApplicationTest</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Do you have any custom error handlers?  What is the `$traceError` property for?  PHPUnit throws an exception when an assertion fails.  It is likely that somewhere in your code, you are catching generic exceptions which prevents PHPUnit from behaving as you expect.  I don't see a problem in any of the code that you posted, unfortunately.

Comment: @Schleis in the link in my post it explains that the `$traceError = true` will print the reasons for a failed assertion. And I think you're right with the exception catching, because I just added `$rrrr->getName()` to the function before the 'hello1' is printed and 'hello1' didn't print and no error was shown.